# How to expose azure managed api openapi v3 yaml file via REST link

Tags: azure-api-management

I'm having trouble exposing a link to download an open API v3 spec from my managed API. I've seen [this blog](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/azure-api-management-openapi-v3-preview/) stating:

> **Export of OpenAPI Specification v3** files in the JSON and YAML formats in the azure portal and the developer portal, as well as through [the REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/2019-01-01/apiexport/get) (YAML only).

However, clicking on this link as you can see shows a 404.

all I could see through the [following blog page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-the-preview-of-openapi-specification-v3-support-in-azure-api-management/) is that

> You can also export the specifications through the visual interface of the Azure portal or a REST API call, with the format query parameter set to `openAPI-link`.

I'm unaware of the context of where this call is made (against our API endpoint??). any assistance is appreciated.

> I've tried `https://my.api.endpoint.com?format=openapi-link` with no luck)

> ```
>  {
>    "statusCode": 404,
>    "message": "Resource not found" 
>  }
> ```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to export api from Azure API managemnt,we can use the following API to do that. It will export the Api Definition in OpenAPI 3.0 Specification as YAML document to Storage Blob. Then we can download the file from the blob

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/{serviceName}/apis/{apiId}?format=openapi-link 
&export=true&api-version=2019-12-01
```

For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/2019-12-01/api-export/get#exportapi)